# Counting values between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to count all the rows in the month of December:

```
select COUNT(*) from quicklabdumpgood
where [Date Entered]>'20111131'
and [Date Entered]<'20120101'
```

but my problem is that:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

It looks like some of the `[date entered]` fields are empty. How do I NOT count them if they are empty?

Please note that `[date entered]` is `DATE` not `DATETIME`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - OP stated that `[date entered]` is `DATE` type. About the case-sensitive thing, that depends on the COLLATION of the database.

Comment: does this mean lamak is wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no November 31st.  : )

Comment: @chris - Its not a typo, to do the filter, it must convert `'20111131'` to a date, and that is causing the error

Comment: @Norla Sorry, my mistake, you are right! Big upvote from my side!